# About an iOS app size when integrating third party frameworks

Tags: ios

I tried to get answer to my question searching among other questions already answered but I did not.
Actual, my question is very simple:
I am trying to integrate third party frameworks to support Ads in my iOS app (AdMob by Google e MoPub). What I can see is that these framework are really huge (>10MB each one). So, I guess the final app size will be very large, also for a trivial app. How can I handle this. I think this is a common situation. Am I missing something in integrating third party frameworks? How do you handle Ads integration in your apps? If you want to have AdMob and you download the latest GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-6.12.2, it weighs 13.4MB!
I hope my question is clear enough.
Wait for answers, thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked the size of your app after doing `Product` -> `Archive`. Just because the download was 13.4MB doesn't mean your app will be 13.4MB + your compiled code.

Comment: As far as I know, the frameworks contain all of the architecture slices, which are currently available (5 for now: armv7, armv7s, arm64, i386 and x64). So this means, that the size of the app provided for specific architecture will be approximately 5 times less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to make a Release build (e.g., by using the Archive command) of an app that links those frameworks and check the final size?

When the app is built for release, all debug information and other symbols that are required for linking are stripped out, so the binary size will shrink **a lot**, usually.

Be assured that a release build will be much smaller than a debug build and that the debug build will be smaller than the sum of the individual binaries that you are linking together. You could go, in specific cases I am thinking of, from 200MB pre-link to 2MB after linking in release mode. Generally speaking, unless you have many images or other kind of media bundled with a library, the size will not be a great concern (compiled code shrinks a whole lot) -- but there is no other way than linking the library and see what the linker comes out with to know the real size...

Comment: Actually I did not, above all because I have not got the license yet. Anyway, is this the only way to know the final size?

Comment: Anyway, I was mainly interesting in knowing if the problem I posted was a concern not just for me. I guess almost everything who wants to integrate third party frameworks for Ads support can have my issue and so I was wondering what is the best policy to overcome it. Because I think 20 MB just for Ads frameworks is really a large size.
Instead, if making a Release build overcomes this problem, sorry for annoying you, just wanted to know for sure.

Comment: Reading you edit, now that issue is much more clear for me. I hope you are right about size shrinking, but I think so. I have just to try, then. Thanks for now, I hope I can try as soon as possibile to get my desired answer.

Comment: Hello. I tested what you said directly with a device available. In fact, you was absolutely right. So, no problem with app size in release mode.
Thank you.